# VWCUK Cookie (Example VWCUK200)

Tags: cookies

Which app/site sets this cookie? If you search for Cookies in your browser, it's quite likely that this cookie is set by number of independent sites/domains.

Comment: I think we need a bit more information to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is set by a JavaScript provided by unicast.

Answer (score 2):

This cookie is probably used by some tracking / ads company as it is featured in this **[Kill Bad Cookies](http://gist.github.com/324414)** script.